# Supabase. How to insert user information when registering in another table?

Tags: postgresql, supabase

When registering a new client on my site (Supabase + Vue.js), how do I create an entry in the %BASE_NAME% database with the following fields: uuid of the client who registered, and a JSON field with an empty object.
Somewhere in the documentation I saw, it seems, similar examples, but I can’t find them now.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a job for a trigger and a function.

You can't query the auth table directly, so you need to do create a function that does this work for you, triggered when a new entry is made to auth.users.

Some details here:
https://nikofischer.com/supabase-how-to-query-users-table

And a video describing the process here:
https://egghead.io/lessons/supabase-use-supabase-to-subscribe-to-database-events-with-postgres-triggers